# Why do we need to provide JDK library for Android project?

Tags: java, android, jar, sdk

Android Sdk wraps Java library classes but Android Studio still forces us to provide our local JDK path and includes additional java library to the project. It will not let you use it anyways. Why is that? I could not figure out a way to exclude it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK uses JDK to compile project's .java files to .class bytecode, which then converted to .dex files. java.* and javax.* from android.jar are APIs that you use in your android app. Implementation of this APIs may differ from the corresponding Oracle JDK implementation.

> Dalvik does not align to Java SE nor Java ME class library profiles[3][4] (e.g., Java ME classes, AWT or Swing are not supported). Instead it uses its own library[5] built on a subset of the Apache Harmony Java implementation.

[Wikipedia - Comparison of Java and Android API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API)